# Mixare Augmented view donesn't rotate back to portrait

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, augmented-reality

Someone could tell me if there's a known bug about 
AugmentedViewController rotation?

I saw that Markers has a strange behaviour in landscape mode so I've 
checked about subviews rotation colouring it to see the different 
layers, and I've found the next issue.

1) MixareViewController (mainViewController) rotates well. 
2) AugviewController.view (overlayview) has the same behaviour:

- OK in portrait mode
- OK when rotate to landscape mode.
- When I go back to portrait mode, overlay view keeps in landscape 
  mode, so when markers are in middle-low of the screen they dissapear.

Has somene have the same issue and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance for any help provided.